# xml parsing problems php

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem.

I have 2 php scripts, one which sends xml data using curl and one which is supposed to read the posted data.

The problem is the reciever script is not getting any of the elements in the xml.

Any help would be appriciated.

SENDER SCRIPT:

```
<?php
$xml = '
<SMS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/send/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xsd">
    <auth>
        <user>yourusername</user>
        <pass>yourpassword</pass>
    </auth>
    <originator>your_sender_name</originator>
    <messages>
        <msg id="1" gsm="440000000000">
            <text>Please come for you appointment tomorrow morning at 12:45</text>
        </msg>          
        <msg id="1" gsm="440000000000">
            <text>Please come for you appointment tomorrow morning at 14:00</text>
        </msg>
    </messages>
</SMS>';

function sendMessages($xml) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    //$url = "https://sapi.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/send/xml.php";
    $url = "http://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/send/xml.php";

    $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

echo sendMessages($xml);
//echo $xml;
?>
```

RECIEVER SCRIPT:

```
<?php
function logResult() {
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($postdata); 
    $xp = new domxpath($dom); 
    $messages = $xp->query("//SMS/auth"); 
    //var_dump($messages);
    foreach ($messages as $node) {
        //var_dump($node);
        return $node->getAttribute('user');
        //$node->getAttribute('sentdate');
        //$node->getAttribute('donedate');
    }
}
echo logResult();
?>
```

Comment: The sender xml is here http://fixee.org/paste/k5i6qca/, stackoverflow is weird sometimes ;(

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: your message hasn't shown up, can you repost please.

Comment: @Kyle: I just made the source code and the XML more readable by correctly indenting the lines... No answer from my side yet.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig: Danke (Thank you)

Comment: What does `echo sendMessages($xml);` say?
Try `print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));` after the `$response = curl_exec($curl);` and check the data.

Comment: echo sendMessages($xml); = nothing (blank);

print_r = 

Array ( [url] => http://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/send/xml.php [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 141 [request_size] => 672 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.196095 [namelookup_time] => 0.002164 [connect_time] => 0.002307 [pretransfer_time] => 0.002315 [size_upload] => 528 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 2692 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0.196029 [redirect_time] => 0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get `DOMDocument` to even load this XML string, with or without the namespace. I have no idea why.

I'd suggest using [SimpleXMLElement](http://us.php.net/simplexmlelement). I use it a lot, and it works great. I was also able to get it to parse your XML string.